# Identify root cause of occasional slow INSERTS/UPDATES in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a C# application executing a constant flow of SQL statements (queries, inserts, updates) against a SQL Server (2019 Standard if that matters) database. Most of these operations take a few milliseconds (ca. 2-50) to execute.

However in the course of the day, there are occasional cases where the same SQL statement would be several magnitudes slower and take seconds to execute, for example 5 or 10 or even >30 seconds, in which case the operation is aborted.
The issue may not happen for several days or 1-2 per day as well as phases of 10-15 minutes with several of such cases. That all looks pretty random.

I am desperately searching for the cause of this behaviour.

What I have found out and ruled our so far:

- the issue is not specific to a particular statement. The issue is also not specific to certain data. It is the exact same statement (with minor differences in the actual values) that takes 5 milliseconds in most cases, but sometimes so much longer.
- I believe that the issue is limited to inserts & updates. I have not seen a query causing the issue so far.
- the issue is not specific to a particular date/time of the day. Neither does it appear to be a workload bottleneck. My application is the only software using that SQL Server and the problem happens even at times where workload is pretty low. Everything runs in a single VM ware virtual machine, but the IT department is claiming that the machine has no issues and I have no evidence to prove otherwise.
- Quite interestingly, I have seen cases where a particular statement would "hang" while similar other statements execute in milliseconds at the same time. (my application is a multi-threaded application)
- The issue does not seem to be caused by a deadlock. SQL Server seems to detect deadlock situation and throws a specific error in such cases, which does not happen here.
- it seems as if the statement is blocked or held up by something. I have also seen rare cases where a statement would be submitted & hang, another statement is later also submitted and also hangs, until the first statement completes or is aborted, after which the second statement also completes pretty much immediately.
- the application may perform multiple transactions in parallel. However, these are not longer than 5-100 milliseconds. It is therefore not plausible that one statement would hang several seconds and wait for some other long running transaction to finish.

After searching through my code and days of logs, I am running out of ideas. Needless to say, I was not able to reproduce the issue in a development environment.

How can I retrieve more information why individual statements take so long and identify the root cause?
Possible theories/suspects:

- could SQL Server be limited or hang due to hardware/OS resources - such as IO? I am pretty sure it is not CPU or memory and network should not matter with everything on the same machine. How would I find out about that?
- could it be that problematic statements trigger some SQL Server internal catch-up, e.g. flushing cashes, etc. That should however not take several seconds - I hope.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Might be long `FlushCache` you need to check the logs, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74292/flushcache-messages-appearing-in-log-at-specific-times. Might be statistics update, do you have them set to asynchronous? Might be a blocking chain, use this script while the blocking is happening https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/20/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/

Comment: Deadlocks are a special class of blocking where two (or more) processes are trying to lock the same set of table/index resources but in different orders - SQL Server usually detects deadlocks within 5 seconds and rolls back the least expensive transaction. Well-behaved blocking can still cause delays as the queue works through the blocked process list.

Comment: Do you have access to the Windows OS hosting the SQL Server instance? If you think it's to do with insert/update operations it could be worth watching Disk Write Latency and Disk Write Queue Length counters in Performance Monitor whilst trying to trigger the issue. It could be due to sub-optimal storage, but it could also be interference from other guests on the VMware host.